# logarithmic interval and sum up trapezoids for integration

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get a integration which the limits of the integral should be in logarithmic intervals, in another word, if "a" and "b" are the higher and lower limits of integration, then the points would be `xi=a*(b/a)^(i/N)` for `N` intervals. so I wrote the code to sum up the trapezoids in python as below and I gave it a simple formula like `f(x)= x^2` (since my actual formula is very complicated), but it doesn't give me any result. I wanted to know if I am in a right track or no. S here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

a = 2
b = 4
N = 100

def integrate(f, a, b, N):
    for i in range(1,N):
        h = a*((b/a)**(i/float(N)))*(((a/b)**(1/float(N)))-1)  # our intervals
        xi = a*((b/a)**(i/float(N)))
        xii = a*((b/a)**(i+1)/float(N))
        s = ((1/2.0)*(f(a)+f(a*(b/a)**(1/float(N)))))*(a*(((b/a)**(1/float(N)))-1)) #the area of the first trapezoid 
        s = s +((f(xi)+ f(xii))*(1/2.0))*h

    return s

def F(x):
    return x**2

print integrate (F, a, b, N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arithmetic is off *somewhere*.  For instance, this line is missing a pair of parentheses:

```
    xii = a*((b/a)**(i+1)/float(N))
```

Should be

```
    xii = a*((b/a)**((i+1)/float(N)))
```

Since you're having trouble debugging this, I suggest a few basic steps:

1. Use liberal `print` statements to track intermediate results
2. use intermediate variables to help with that tracking, and to avoid repeated computations.  The less you have to type nested parentheses, the lower the chance of error.
3. See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: so the logic of the integration is right? also in the code i suppose to have 99 values for "h", but it gives me only one value. did I make mistake in writing the range?

Comment: I don't follow that statement: a simple `print` shows that you get 99 values for `h`.

Comment: I'm not doing a detailed review of the integration logic; the answer I get is wrong, but you've made it difficult to proofread your code (which would be generally outside of the SO charter).

Comment: yes I know..it seems a mess...but how can I write an easier code for getting an integration by using logarithmic intervals...I searched on internet but unfortunately couldn't find anything useful...

Comment: I already gave you suggestions; you haven't taken them.  The Internet doesn't necessarily have solutions for all of your homework; you have to derive some of them.  Your code is *close*, but you'll need to follow better programming practices.  Meaningless variable names and repeated work damage the readability.  For instance, you repeatedly compute a/b, i/float(n), etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your indenting is screwed up. You need to indent your for-loop, and unindent after defining `integrate`. Second, if `xi` is supposed to be the left end of your interval and `xii` the right end, then you should start with i=0. Third, you can use one variable to define others. So if `h` is supposed to be the length of the interval, you can define `xi` and `xii` first, then just put `h=xii-xi`, and so on.

Comment: xi and xii are any generic points and are next to each other. I didn't include i=0, because I derived the first trapezoid area by putting i=0 and then wrote the sum loop for adding other trapezoids to it. and sorry since I;m new to programming, I didn't understand what you mean by indenting and unindenting..!